# angular2: Nested loops in templates without emitting HTML

Tags: angular, angular2-template

My data looks something like this

```
this.data = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];
```

and I'd like to put the each of the values 1..6 in a `<td>` tag of a table.

My problem is, that the outer loop needs to be within some kind of tag, but I don't want to spoil the HTML structure. My current solution is the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <dummy *ngFor="let a of data;">
            <td *ngFor="let b of a;">
                {{b}}
            <td>
        <dummy>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There is no component associated with `<dummy>`.

This works, but I doubt this is the intended way of doing this. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **template syntax with ngFor** this will not ruin you HTML structure,

demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/562hB7qNUhsv7mO6sRVV?p=preview

```
<table>
    <tr>

        <template ngFor let-a [ngForOf]="data" let-i="index">
            <td *ngFor="let b of a;">
                {{b}}
            <td>
        </template>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the multi dimensional array for anything in the table then for this loop you can just flatten the array and use one `ngFor` on the flattened array.

To flatten the array you can do something like:

```
this.flatData = [].concat.apply([], this.data);
```

You can then use your flatData property in the html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let item of flatData">
            {{item}}
        <td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is the alternative I was thinking about. However, the code above only isolates my problem, and this approach would not have been very practicable in my application. But thanks anyway!